# "field mapping is invalid"

Tags: data-loader

The cmd for the Dataloader is telling me the "Field mapping is invalid", even though the sdl file was built in the Apex dataloader tool. I have triple checked the mappings and there's nothing woring with them.

I am a full system admin and have read/write access to every field on the custom object, so am a little confused.

Other things I have tried which made no difference:
-Deleted unmatched columns in the csv
-Checked to make sure there were no white spaces in the sdl file
-Used field labels to map rather than the API label
-Have tried versions 20.0 and 33.0 of the dataloader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be getting field name in error message, Check that the field quoted directly after the error message is:

1. Visible to the profile being used by the user signed in to the Data Loader: check the field level security; if it worked in sandbox and not in production, check the differences between sandbox and production's profiles and field level security
2. Not deleted
3. Spelled correctly in the .sdl file

Comment: Add a missed reason, wrong ``sfdc.entity`` in ``process-conf.xml`` will cause field mapping invalid problem.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake in the end. I hadn't changed the object name in the xml file!!

Comment: I did this myself